# SharePoint Online and Flows - how to remove quitted employee correctly?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user, power-automate, user-accounts

I created flow that uses "Grant permissions" action, and it uses SharePoint Group with users. One of employees has left the company, and (as I understand) IT Team deleted this account. But this user was still in SharePoint Group so my flow got his email and crashed on "Grant permissions" step:

> cannot resolve user jane.doe@company.com

So all my approval instances created yesterday crashed.
As I suppose IT Team should not delete user, but reset password and disable(?). Imho we need to keep users for audit/project management history..

**What is correct procedure of removing resigned user in Microsoft 365?** Do You have any best-practices or what do You use?

**upd.:** Tnak You for link Steve. Looks like there something from MS:
[Remove or Delete a former employee](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/remove-former-employee?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tenant (free developer account), the Apps Launcher (that 9-dot 3x3 grid in upper left) has an **Admin** label in "All Apps". User accounts are controlled from there. User accounts can be deleted (with a 30-day possible recovery) from the Users => Active Users list. If account deletion is not necessarily desired, sign-ins by users can be blocked. The Admin center will keep track of "Deleted users" list. I believe SharePoint keeps track of users who created/modified list/library items anyway, which is what you would want even for long-departed personnel.

Several apps/systems integrate to manage user accounts. You can check [this support article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Thank You for response Steve!
>>  believe SharePoint keeps track of users who created/modified list/library items anyway
yes it does. But Power Automate fails on these deleted users. Also some PS sripts fail too, on these 'broken' users so I don't want to delete them at all..

Answer (score 1):

Best way to delete the user is delete from Microsoft 365 admin center.

After you delete a user, a series of jobs will remove the user from SharePoint. After the next incremental profile import job, the user (or users) will be marked as deleted, the user's profile page will be deleted, and the user's OneDrive will be marked for deletion by the MySite cleanup job.

However sometime user still present sharepoint user info list. that can cause a problem

below are step to delete user from User info list.

Browse to the site and edit the URL by adding the following string to the end of it

/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0

For example, the full URL will resemble the following: https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/people.aspx/membershipGroupId=0

Select the person from the list, and then on the Actions menu, select Delete Users from Site Collection.

For more details please refer the following microsoft docs.

[Remove User](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-users)

Please upvote and accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Thank You Rajat! I hoped someone has practical example, but thank You too!